# how to test function with Fuse.js dependency

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, fuse

I want to implement .test file for the following function:

```
import Fuse from 'fuse.js';
import data from '../dal/data';
async function search(searchedData) {
  // In case searched name is null
  if (!searchedData) {
    return [];
  }

  // load data
  const dataload = await data();
  // set options to filter data
  const options = {
    includeMatches: true,
    // Search in `name'
    keys: ['name'],
  };
  const fuse = new Fuse(dataload, options);
  const matchedList = fuse.search(searchedData)
    .map((element) => element.item);

  return { matchedList };
}

export default search;
```

How to do for Fuse.js, shall I implement a mock data?

Comment: Do you want you implement fuzzy search with it?

Comment: yes, is it possible, I spend hours search how can I define a mock as Fuse

Answer (score 0):

Fuse.js is library that provides fuzzy search based on dynamic configurations pass to it. There are different library which are available such as [fuzzy-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy-search).

Now, the question is how you can mock similar library as fuzzy search as per the comment. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-scalable-search-engine-for-fuzzy-string-matching-751bd09f6074) is a good example of how you can start building your own fuzzy search engine, but to do so, you need to understand what fuzzy search is and how it works.

Now, if you want to know how Fuse.js works with any mock data. I can add some code which might help you to integrate with your existing project.

**Mock Data**

```
// it could be of any type, I am using Array of objects
const mockData = [{
                   name : 'Jason Durham',
                   age : 28,
                   address : 'Newyork city, New York, USA'
                   }, {
                   name : 'Jameson Durham',
                   age : 28,
                   address : 'Cleveland, Ohio, USA'
                   },
                   {
                   name : 'Tintan Groofs',
                   age : 28,
                   address : 'Ohio city, Ohio, USA'
                   }]
```

```
const options = {
  includeScore: true,    // the o/p will include the ranking based on weights
  keys: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      weight: 0.3        // what weightage you want this key in your search result
    },
    {
      name: 'address',
      weight: 0.7        // what weightage you want this key in your search result
    }
  ]
}

// Create a new instance of Fuse
const fuse = new Fuse(mockData, options)

// Now search for 'Man'
const result = fuse.search('nwyork');
console.log(result);
```

You can check [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/examples.html#weighted-search) documentation to check how to advance your search and configurable.

You can test the fuzzy search results using a test framework provided that you know the expected values, but it will contain a very broad set of o/p based on your configuration. As of now Fuse.js doesn't provide direct way in their documentation to check for it, but you can create a method based on the ranking you get and create a threshold value for it. This is the way we are testing our search results using Fuse.js, all the results below this threshold is discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did the same thing data in mock but in the test should I use Fuse.js directly or I need another mock for Fuse?

Comment: You can use the same its fine or you can create a new mock data using the above one if this answer clears the things you are asking. please accept and upvote it.

Comment: thanks but my question is about Fuse  and not the data

Comment: I guess it is unclear from the question, but I guess you can actually use Fuse.js anywhere and with your own configuration. I have already implemented that in our project if you need any help with the configuration, I can provide it.

Comment: My question is not about how can I use FUse, I use it in my previous project, my quest is about how to implement .test for my code ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is ".test" about? How it is relevant with fuse.js?

Comment: I mean to test my code with Jest framework, so I need to implement search.test.js for my search.js code

Comment: Just added more info in the answer hope this might give you the direction.